# Converting concrete child to parent that has generic specialization in C#

Tags: c#, generics, events

I have simple code:

```
public interface IEvent {}

public class ObjectClickEvent : IEvent {        
    public Object Object;
    public ObjectClickEvent(Object object) {
        Object = object;
    }
}

public abstract class EventReceiver<T> where T : IEvent {
    protected readonly Controller Controller;
    protected EventReceiver(Controller controller) {
        Controller = controller;
    }

    public abstract void ReceiveEvent(T @event);
}

public class ObjectClickEventReceiver : EventReceiver<ObjectClickEvent> {
    public ObjectClickEventReceiver(Controller controller) : base(controller) {
    }
    public override void ReceiveEvent(ObjectClickEvent @event) {
    }
}
```

Then I want to initialize all my receivers inside a controller

```
   var receivers = new List<EventReceiver<IEvent>>();
   var receiver = new LetterClickEventReceiver(this);
   receivers.Add(receiver);
```

But got a compile error:

```
Argument type 'LetterClickEventReceiver' is not assignable to parameter type
'ScriptsV2.Core.Controller.EventReceivers.EventReceiver<IEvent>'
```

The question is why it happens if I state that my concrete receiver extends EventReceiver < IEvent >? Why child cannot be added to list of parent objects?

Answer (score 0):

`A<Derived>` can be made compatible with `A<Base>` by making the type parameter of the base interface covariant. The `out` keyword does this.

```
public interface EventReceiver<out T> where T : IEvent {...}
```

Then update your collections to use these interfaces instead of referencing a class.

Variance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/

Comment: Can I do it while still using some abstract class, so I dont have to copypaste constructor and controller field for each event? Because if I just add interface IEventReceiver<out T> where T : IEvent{} then I still got the same error.

Comment: Can you correct me please, I now have "public interface IEventReceiver<out T> where T : IEvent {}" and "public abstract class EventReceiver<T> : IEventReceiver<T> where T : IEvent { ... }" and still got the very same error. However if I remove abstract class and make concrete ObjectClickEvent extend IEventReceiver then everything compiles fine.

Comment: Unfortunately the `T` here is in input position, so all you can do is to make *contra*variant interface. Which means the `IEventReceiver<T>` cannot be treated as `IEventReceiver<IEvent>`, thus cannot be stored in a common list other than `LIst<object>`.

Comment: Classes don't permit variance (only interfaces and delegate types do) so you'd need to have your collections parameterized by the interface type.